# Value of type "AnyObject.Protocol" does not conform to expected dictionary value type 'AnyObject'

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I'm trying to use `Parse` to save units to a player's army. This code is throwing up the `error`:

> Value of type "AnyObject.Protocol" does not conform to expected dictionary value type 'AnyObject'

I think I have to cast the `dictionary` somehow. Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
  let unitParse = PFObject(className: "playerArmies", dictionary: ["\(PFUser)":AnyObject])
  unitParse["UnitName"] = selectedUnit.name
  unitParse["CurrentHP"] = selectedUnit.hitPoints
  unitParse["MaxHP"] = selectedUnit.hitPointsMax
  unitParse.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
    (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    if (success) {
      // The object has been saved.
    } else {
      // There was a problem, check error.description
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is in this code:

```
["\(PFUser)":AnyObject]
```

You are setting the class type `AnyObject` as the value of dictionary. You need to pass actual object there. It is not clear from your question, that what object you need to pass. I think you want something like:

```
["PFUser" : "\(PFUser)"]
```

Comment: `AnyObject` is not a class; it's a protocol